# Mahout Using Command line to create cluster--Problems

Tags: command-line, mahout, canopy

I am trying to cluster the following example set of coordinates:

```
(1,1) , (2,1) , (1,2), (2,2), (3,3), (8,8), (8,9), (9,8), (9,9)
```

These coordinates should form two clusters:

```
(1,1) , (2,1) , (1,2), (2,2), (3,3)
```

AND

```
(8,8), (8,9), (9,8), (9,9)
```

This is how I proceeded:

**Step** 1: Stored this as a tab-separated data in a file on hadoop as:

```
1 1

2 1

1 2

2 2

3 3

8 8

8 9

9 8

9 9
```

**Step** 2:Converted this file into Sequence file as:

`$mahout seqdirectory --input my.data --output kdraft -c UTF-8`

**Step** 3:Created a Sparse data file as:

`$mahout seq2sparse -i kdraft -o kfinal -wt tf`

**Step** 4:
Ran Canopy alogrithm to generate clusters as:

`$mahout canopy -i kfinal/tf-vectors --clustering -o xz -t1 5 -t2 2 -ow`

**Step** 4:Dumped output

`$mahout clusterdump --input xz/clusters-0-final  --pointsDir xz/clusteredPoints/ --output /home/ashokharnal/data/c.txt`

The output appears in c.txt as:

C-0{n=1 c=[4.000, 2.000, 4.000, 4.000, 4.000] r=[]}     Weight: [props - optional]:  Point:
    1.0: [4.000, 2.000, 4.000, 4.000, 4.000]

I wanted to know which coordinates are in which cluster? I am not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

The clustering assignment information should be in xz/clusteredPoints

try this:
mahout seqdumper -i xz/clusteredPoints/part-m-00000

it should give output where each line is the assignment of a data point to a cluster.  When I process for my work, the cluster number appears first, then a value indicating the likelihood, a file identifier for the data point, then finally coordinate information

sorry I can't be more specific, I can't get the example to run and reproduce the output you pasted.

There is mention of the clusteredPoints directory in this example:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Quick+tour+of+text+analysis+using+the+Mahout+command+line

good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is not correct ! By doing so, you get just one vector ! So, you should first write a hadoop program that takes each line as a value and a whatever unique key. The output format of your hadoop program must be sequential output format. Then, use Seqsparse to convert your result (sequential file) to mahout vectors. Finally apply Kmeans or whatever your mahout clustering algorithm.